# Save JTextField inputs to text file

Tags: java, swing

I have a form created for a users information. I need the data that is entered into the JTextFields to save to a text file. I have this action listener that builds the GUI when a button is pressed. Need help saving the data...

```
        static class Register implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            //Creates new JPanel 
            JFrame rFrame = new JFrame ("Register, Please Enter Your Information.");
            rFrame.setVisible(true);
            rFrame.setSize(800,800);
            JPanel rPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2));
            rFrame.add(rPanel);

            //Creates register form
            JLabel Rfirstname = new JLabel("Firstname: "); rPanel.add(Rfirstname);
            JTextField firstname = new JTextField(40); rPanel.add(firstname);
            JLabel Rsurname = new JLabel("Surname: "); rPanel.add(Rsurname);
            JTextField surname = new JTextField(40); rPanel.add(surname);
            JLabel Rdob = new JLabel("D.O.B: "); rPanel.add(Rdob);
            JTextField dob = new JTextField(40); rPanel.add(dob);
            JLabel Raddress = new JLabel("Address: "); rPanel.add(Raddress);
            JTextField address = new JTextField(40); rPanel.add(address);
            JLabel Rpostcode = new JLabel("Post Code: "); rPanel.add(Rpostcode);
            JTextField postcode = new JTextField(40); rPanel.add(postcode);
            JLabel Rallergy = new JLabel("Allergy Info: "); rPanel.add(Rallergy);
            JTextField allergy = new JTextField(40); rPanel.add(allergy);
            JLabel Rcontact = new JLabel("Contact Details: "); rPanel.add(Rcontact);
            JTextField contact = new JTextField(40); rPanel.add(contact);

    }
```

Comment: Add a button with an ActionListener, Open a new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Path_string)); anduse the method of BufferedWriter for writing Strings?

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of your variables are correct, others are not. Be consistent!!! Notice how the forum incorrectly highlight the incorrect names???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write Code like that (in the function where you define your textfields, in your case in your method you showed in your question):

```
JTextField firstName=new JTextField();
    JButton but=new JButton("Save");
    but.addActionListener(e1->{
        try{
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("asdf.txt"));
            bw.write(firstName.getText());
            bw.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

In this example, i simply write the Text of firstName. If you want to write all fields, you have to concat them (or something like that.
Furthermore, you have to modify your path (If you use Windows, you also have to use / instead of \ for your path).

Comment: If you don't want to do it on a button-click, you can do it anywhere you have Access to your JTextfields.

Comment: Looks good, getting this error "Lambda expression's parameter e cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope" where '(e->{'

Comment: In my example, you overwrite the file each time you click save. If you want to store the submits to several files, you could add some Parameters to the path- or filename. If you want to append, you can search on google how to do it, there are several questions regarding this on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Your Problem: You already use e for your ActionListener. Simply Change e to any other string, for example e1. I modified my Code above.